# count words more accurately

Tags: javascript, html, counter, onkeyup

Is it possible to make this function to count words more accurately and most important, count the word inside a editable div?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.word_count').each(function() {
    var input = '#' + this.id;
    var count = input + '_count';
    $(count).show();
    word_count(input, count);
    $(this).keyup(function() { word_count(input, count) });
});

});

function word_count(field, count) {

var number = 0;
var matches = $(field).val().match(/\b/g);
if(matches) {
    number = matches.length/2;
}
$(count).text( number + ' word' + (number != 1 ? 's' : '') + ' aprox' );

}
```

Comment: Working code is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: How exactly is this function not accurate? Provide us an example where it returns inexact count. The reason why it doesn't work in a div is probably because div's content is retrieved via .html() or .text(), not .val().

Comment: What about regex? .textContent.split(/\w+/).length

Comment: Hi @amik! On a text box this counts ex: 64 words and in microsoft word the same text counts 60 words. But this is strange because other word set can count 57 on textbox and ms word counts 60 an so on...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`var numwords = $(field).val().match(/\S+/g).length;`

Comment: how can i write it if i want to count it as 4 words whenever a bracket will come?

Comment: so countThis("an example (sentence)"); should return 6?

Answer (score 0):

From my personal library:

```
var s = "Is it possible to make this function to count words more accurately and most important, count the word inside a editable div?";
s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, "");
s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi, " ");
s = s.replace(/\n /, "\n");
var countresult = s.split(' ').length;
alert("The string:\""+s+"\" and the word count is "+countresult+".");
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/farondomenic/XAvh6/ for working example.

Comment: Any luck on getting your issue to work as solved?  I am curious on which method you picked that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the .split() method. Grab the element and make an array. Very straight forward and easy to code. I don't think you need more of an example than this to know if you like the idea or not. Any questions, I will be around...
[W3 Schools Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)